# Call groovy script

Tags: groovy

Hi i have written groovy script like:

```
class Test{
    public Object testComposedRules() {
        String ruleACode = {age, product -> def discount = 0; if(age<10 && product=="Toys") discount=10; println "hi $discount"; return discount};
        Closure ruleA = (Closure) Eval.me(ruleACode);

        Object object = ruleA.call(9, "Toys");

        return object;
    }    
}
```

when i tried to access this class from another main class; i cant get the test class

```
public static void main() {
     Test a = new Test();
     a.testComposedRules();
}
```

i m getting error it does not exists; is there any way to access groovy functions from java class;

Comment: How are you compiling the classes?  Are they in the same package?  What is the actual error (a stacktrace always helps)

Comment: Also, you seem to be storing a Closure in a String `ruleACode`, then trying to `Eval.me` this string.  `ruleACode` wil have the value `Script1$_run_closure1@f00e0f` (or similar), so the Eval.me will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the case difference of A in definition and call is a typo in the question?

If not, try `A.testComposedRules();`

Comment: hi thanx for replying and sorry it was typo error in question but my problem is when i try to build my application it gives me error can not find symbol Class Test i have tested from target that it does not create class file for groovy script class

Comment: i have added gmaven plugin also but i m not getting the class; i get an compile time error that can not find symbol